# "match" function does not work on Laravel Code

Tags: php, laravel

```
class ClickWithContent
{
    public $LeftUser;
 
    public function y()
    {
        $value = match(1) {
            1 => 'Hii..', // <-------- syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
            2 => 'Hello..',
            default => 'Match not found !',
        };
    }
}
```

On the above code line I tried to use match function instead of switch statement. But I get following error on Line mentioned on the code.

> syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: What's your PHP version? `match` is a PHP 8 feature and produces this error if used in prior versions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### PHP Match

`match()` expression according to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php), the docs state:

> Match expressions are available as of PHP 8.0.0.

Apparently you are using php version < 8.0.0. make sure you are using PHP 8+, you can try checking your php version using `phpinfo()` inside your code or `php -v` on your terminal.

### Alternate

An alternative for `match()` is, (or should I say `match()` is an alternative of) what we call `switch()` you can simply replicate what you are trying here by using `switch()` (not to forget that switches don't work with integers because 0 will simply evaluate as false and vice versa) so you can try something like this:

```
$target = 1;
$value = null;
switch((string) ($target)) // typecast to string
{
    case "1":
        $value = 'Hi..';
        break;
    case "2":
        $value = 'Hello..'
        break;
    default:
        $value = 'Match not found !'
}
```

I hope that explains your problem.